# Install matomo in xampp

Tags: matomo

I am trying to install matomo by following the instructions in the website. But no luck, i keep on getting errors. I am using xampp to host the matomo.

First, I downloaded matomo, extracted it inside htdocs folder of my xampp.  Then I go to localhost/matomo.  It shows the installation welcome page. I click on Next and after a while got error "No database selected"

I researched and i read something that I need to create a config.ini.php and specify the database. And so I created a database in phpmyadmin called "matomo", then created a config.ini.php file. Then when I go to localhost/matomo, i get an error saying that matomo is already installed and that "matomo.option" doesn't exist.

Why is the matomo installation have to be this difficult? Has someone successfully did it? If you'll down vote, at least please let me know why so i can provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after researching further, it seems after clicking Next, Matomo is already doing a system check which takes too long to complete. So the solution is to increase the `max_execution_time` found in xampp/php/php.ini to `90`.

This will give matomo enough time to complete its process. I hope others will find this useful.